# Aborted connection 3 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.21.0.1'

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

Did anyone face already that error, when creating a MariaDB with docker-compose in IntelliJ ?

I simply created a docker-compose.yml and added the lines below. After running the compose file and trying to open the DB with clicking on the Port, this error in the logs appear.

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: mariadb:10.9.4
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: 'uebung'
      MARIADB_USER: 'user'
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mariadb
      - ./initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d-
volumes:
  data:
```

```
2023-03-10 13:40:23 2023-03-10 12:40:23+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.11.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
2023-03-10 13:40:23 2023-03-10 12:40:23+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2023-03-10 13:40:23 2023-03-10 12:40:23+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.11.2+maria~ubu2204 started.
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB upgrade not required
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.11.2-MariaDB-1:10.11.2+maria~ubu2204 source revision cafba8761af55ae16cc69c9b53a341340a845b36 as process 1
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=4096 bytes)
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 46902; transaction id 14
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 230310 12:40:24
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2023-03-10 13:40:24 2023-03-10 12:40:24 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
2023-03-10 13:40:24 Version: '10.11.2-MariaDB-1:10.11.2+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2023-03-10 13:40:37 2023-03-10 12:40:37 3 [Warning] Aborted connection 3 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.21.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)
```

I tried already deleting the images/container, also started docker again. Deleted the cache of docker and also tried a different port..

I also found similar error in stack overflow which couldn't solve my problem. Would be great if anyone has an idea what's the error here.

OS: macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7
Docker: Docker Desktop 4.14.1 (91661)

[Connection setup in IntelliJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K5X4.png)

Comment: What are the connection details set in IntelliJ? Do they match the credentials used when setting up the database?

Comment: Do u mean View/Tool Windows/Data Base? Is it required to setup the credentials there as well?

Comment: What do you mean by _as well_? You have to tell IntelliJ that you want to connect to a certain database and how to do so.

Comment: Apologize, I'm doing it the first time. It makes sense. I attached a Picture from this window in the original thread. Could you please check if this looks correct?

Comment: In the screenshot your database is called `uebung` (as opposed to `test` in the question). You have to enter that as well. The rest seems to be ok.

Comment: after writing 'uebung' in the field of database name, I was doing again docker-compose down and up, but there is still this issue: prdke-database-1  | 2023-03-10 13:45:50 5 [Warning] Aborted connection 5 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.26.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)

Comment: What is in your `initdb`? Also, there seems to be an additional `-` in the line where you mount initdb

Comment: Also, what errors do you get from IntelliJ (not from docker)?

Comment: There is just an sql File for the DB. But I also created a new project without this init.. 

In IntelliJ is the same error: prdke-database-1  | 2023-03-10 13:48:44 6 [Warning] Aborted connection 6 to db: 'unconnected' user: 'unauthenticated' host: '172.26.0.1' (This connection closed normally without authentication)

Comment: Or do I access the DB wrong ? If I clock on the linked Port 3306:3306 it opens a browser windows with the url 'http://localhost:3306'. Is it possible to enter the configuration page of MariaDB normally?

I tried now to to press Test Connection in the configuration window in IntelliJ and it says: 
DBMS: MariaDB (ver. 10.9.4-MariaDB-1:10.9.4+maria~ubu2204)
Case sensitivity: plain=exact, delimited=exact
Driver: MariaDB Connector/J (ver. 3.0.7, JDBC4.2)
Ping: 14 ms
SSL: no

So from the side of IntelliJ it seems like its working?

Comment: That means, you never really tried to connect to the database?

Comment: Since its my second time, I was used to just press on the Port in the docker container :D last time I used MySQL.. does this provide MyPHPAdmin out of the box bc as I can remember, I came directly to the config Page in the browser haha #newbieproblems but thanks for you help, I think now I understand it

Comment: I think when just clicking on that Port in Docker, it could be an unauthorized entry to the database in the local network. Thats why MariaDB blocks the entry.. also there aren't user credentials provided in the request, right?

Comment: Well, an HTTP request on a database port does not really make sense. Also "opening" the port with a browser will of course not do any database authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved my problem. I connect the database like MSpiller mentioned, then I was able to connect the db but I didn't know that MariaDB doesn't allow to press just on the port as I was used from mysql which forwarded me to MyPhPAdmin to configure the database. Now I added the following code to my docker-compose to create a MyPhpAdmin Container to be able to enter the configuration Page at 'https://localhost:8080'

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    image: mariadb:10.9.4
    restart: always
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: 'uebung'
      MARIADB_USER: 'user'
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mariadb
      - ./initdb:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_ARBITRARY: 1
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    depends_on:
      - database
volumes:
  data:
```

Thanks :) Thread can be closed.